# eclipse remove the keybind for comma

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, key-bindings

I've been using eclipse for a while and I have noticed something quite annoying. If I am entering arguments for a function and I hit comma while typing a string, eclipse advances to the next argument rather than typing a comma and the only way to enter a comma is to ether copy an existing comma in the editor with the clipboard or to hit comma/tab until the argument entering system is disengaged. Does anyone know how I could disable this feature (comma or the whole argument entering assist)? There is nothing in the key binding settings.

Comment: Pressing escape exits the assist system.

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 2 possibilities:

1. Either press escape every time (so the assist system is exited)
2. Deactivate the insertion of arguments automatically (preferable if you enter a lot ','):

Second possibility: Java-->Editor-->Content Assist-->uncheck 'Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments'
Then you can autocomplete the method, but no arguments are filled in. The nice thing is in this case that you can write ',' without a problem, but you still see the parameter hints (shown as tooltip).

Here is the link from where I got the information:
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html